# Android tab scrolling lag

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I'm making an app that uses scrollable tabs and I noticed when I have just text within a tab swiping from one to another works seamless, however when I have a page, with 8 buttons that when pressed play an mp3 for example, it takes a while to swipe in and out of that page. This is all being done with `Fragments`. I've noticed some apps (like Googles Play Music app) have tabs that have a lot more interactive content than mine and the scrolling is fine. Does anyone know offhand how to speed up performance on tabs? I've tried Googling for a solution but I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Try turning on hardware acceleration (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling)

Comment: That helped a little bit but it's still pretty laggy compared to other apps

Answer (score 2):

It's quite difficult to accurately provide a fix for the performance of your app without seeing any code or seeing it in action but here are some general tips. The swiping is choppy because the next tab is taking a while to draw and the transition is taking a while to animate.

- Avoid complicated layouts
- Avoid lots of alpha transparency
- Avoid layouts over other layouts with alpha
- Avoid deeply nested layouts
- Avoid using nested `layout_weight`
- If you are using a ListView/GridView make sure you re-use the view, and use a [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)
- If you are using a lot of images make sure you [cache them](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)
- Try turning on [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling) if your platforms/devices support them

Why don't you try a test where you completely simplify your tabs - have nothing in them? Can you get *good* swiping performance on your app by removing views? Then start building your views back to find out what's causing the problem. This is how I would diagnose the issue.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and when I created the project I had it automatically create a tab template which works fine but there is only 1 character in each of the tabs. I removed that and added buttons which caused the problem. I am using hardware acceleration which didn't help too much but I am using `GridView` so I will try the `ViewHolder`. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If you are making material design swipe tabs with view pager then you can drastically improve performance using
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
This basically sets how many tabs will be running in addition to your current tab. So in place of 3 you can provide your total number of tabs - 1 because your current tab is also running. It is however recommended that you don't keep more than 3 tabs or your app will consume too much resources and might get killed.